# Cannot cast a specific datetime string into a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql

Why can I cast this as a date:

`select cast('3/11/2021 12:00:00 AM' as date)`

But not this:

`select cast('26/02/2021 12:00:00 AM' as date)`

Thanks for your help

Comment: Use `convert` as it allows you to specify the incoming format.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles

Comment: thanks, this seems to work select convert(date, '26/02/2021 12:00:00 AM', 105)

Comment: For example `select convert(datetime, '3/11/2021 12:00:00 AM',103)`

Comment: Well, what did `3/11/2021` give you? March 11th or November 3rd? The fact that I have no idea what you expected should be a hint about why this format is a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast uses "default" format (#101) based on SQL Server locale, whereas CONVERT - as suggested by Dale K allows you to specify the date format that you use.

In your example I believe that: 3/11 is March 11th, and 26/02 is a second day of 26th month which simply doesn't work.

Example using convert:

```
select convert(datetime,'26/02/2021',103)
select convert(datetime,'02/26/2021',101)
```

Comment: And that's why `yyyy-mm-dd` is such a good idea. Gets rid of all the `mm/dd` vs `dd/mm` confusion.

Comment: @Robill Actually `YYYY-MM-DD` is not a good idea either. `SET LANGUAGE French; SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2021-09-14');` See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e2c88cd227e408f51c9ff660c36ecc39

Comment: @AaronBertrand, well in this case the bad idea migth be the `datetime` itself, because your sample would work with `date` or `datetime2`. Anyhow, we should never use `CONVERT` without the third parameter if it comes to culture/language specific formats. From the docs: *"Use the time, date, datetime2 and datetimeoffset data types for new work. These types align with the SQL Standard. They are more portable."*

Comment: @Shnugo So use a specific format only when you know the date/time type will be {in this specific set}? Doesn't that sound like the definition of a bad idea? I'd love to be sure that everyone using my code has the luxury of only using specific types but that's just not how the world works. Also the use of an unsafe format isn't just bad when using with explicit CONVERT() but also in general.

Comment: @AaronBertrand As far as I know you from various great contributions I'm well aware, that you are not the one who needs explanations... I hope we can go d'accord with: *any textual expression of a non-textual type* carries a risk. The most evil is coming through culture and language. So the best hint is: avoid it whenever this is possible and try to enforce some format (e.g. ISO8601) if you cannot avoid it. Agree?

Comment: @Shnugo I agree in principle but I do not agree that `yyyy-mm-dd` is ever a proper format to provide to SQL Server in any context. Any time you use it, you need to attach those additional explanations and caveats or it will burn some portion of the people who learn from it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, well... Knowing this is a `DATE` without a time portion should be fine *in any context*, Shouldn't it? I do not know of any situation where `DATE` would break in this case...

Comment: @Shnugo Because if you don't tell all future readers _this is only safe **because** it's date_ they are going to use it in cases where it's _not_ date, because they don't know the same things you and I do. I know you know this.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, but even the docs tell us (and *all future readers*) that we should not use `datetime` anymore. But you are right of course, that millions of database out there will still use this... I try to stick with ISO8601 (especially in XML or JSON), or the *unseparated* and sometimes I use odbc (`{d'2021-09-14'}`). What's your favorite?

Comment: @Shnugo Haha, right. For all those people that come to Stack Overflow to copy code from an answer and then _also_ go study the documentation and follow all of its advice. I prefer `'YYYYMMDD'` as a literal because - even though it's a bit less readable - it doesn't need any type of coercion and is not vulnerable to misinterpretation by a user (or the computer, based on language, regional, or dateformat settings). I've written a lot about date formats e.g. [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/166771/1186) and, more generally, [here](https://sqlblog.org/dates).